# Python argparse argument with quotes

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

Is there any way I can tell argparse to not eat quotation marks?

For example, When I give an argument with quotes, argparse only takes what's inside of the quotes as the argument. I want to capture the quotation marks as well (without having to escape them on the command line.)

```
pbsnodes -x | xmlparse -t "interactive-00"
```

produces

```
interactive-00
```

I want

```
"interactive-00"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it is the shell that eats them, so python will actually never see them.  Escaping them on the command line may be your only option.

If it's the `\"backslash\"` style escaping you don't like for some reason, then this way should work instead:

```
pbsnodes -x | xmlparse -t '"interactive-00"'
```

Comment: This is exactly the case. The shell sees the quotes as "take whatever's in here even if it contains spaces." And it does so. That's what quotes are *for* in the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution.

Comment: Is it the shell or the c run time library? Shell passes command to the process as is, it's up to the RTL to parse the arguments. I think it's perl's rtl which eats the quotations, or something else down the line.

Comment: @JosVerlinde Your comment does not seem right. Argparse doesn't strip quotes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCGxKL0gsag4lQtMFinYwkX0HIvSS3NT80oCwDIamlAleokpKfGJUDkNpWwloERRJpAJlQZTIAXFGtHqZYk56rGa@FQoAZUogdX8/w8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @wim - I stand corrected - arparse is innocent - I wrongly assumed that using Jupyter no shell would be involved

Answer (score 1):

Command line is parsed into argument vector by python process itself. Depending on how python is built, that would be done by some sort of run-time library. For Windows build, that would be most likely MS Visual C++ runtime library. More details about how it parses command line can be found in Visual C++ documentation: [Parsing C++ command-Line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019#parsing-c-command-line-arguments).

In particular:

- A string surrounded by double quotation marks ("string") is interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space contained within. A quoted string can be embedded in an argument.
- A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash (\") is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark character (").

If you want to see unprocessed command line, on Windows you can do this:

```
import win32api
print(win32api.GetCommandLine())
```

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
'"TEXT"'
```

didn't work with powershell, but with cmd it did

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).