# Optparse- Preserving special characters

Tags: python, special-characters, optparse

I'm using optparse and recently I'm encountering the following problem- I want to pass as an argument a directory name. Something like:

```
./script.py --dir c:\a\b
```

However, optparse eliminates the "\" sign so the related variable remains with the value `c:ab`

Note: This script is being run on Linux machine, that connects to Windows machine and does some stuff. This is why I use the `./` in the script name and the directory is Windows sytle.

How do I make optparse preserve the special characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python argparse argument with quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168666/python-argparse-argument-with-quotes)

Comment: IIRC you can use `/` as path separator without any problem on windows as well.  Try it.

Comment: win you are right but I don't want to force the user to use "/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Python problem; it is your *shell* that parses the backslashes in the command line before sending it to Python. `optparse` is not to blame.

Escape them by doubling the slashes:

```
./script.py --dir c:\\a\\b
```

or put quotes around the argument:

```
./script.py --dir "c:\a\b"
```