# How to handle quotes in python argument

Tags: python, parameter-passing, python-3.5, argparse

I'm using [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) in python3.5. one of my required parameters is a long string that may has any character like single or double quotes. I don't want to limit user how uses this python script and force him to remove this characters. so I'm looking for a solution to handle quotes in my code.

It's my argument parser:

```
class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        sys.stderr.write('Error: %s\n' % message)
        self.print_help()
        sys.exit(2)

    def msg(name=None):
        return '''python3.5 file.py Text'''

parser = MyParser(description='You must pass exactly one arguments after classifier.py . Use quotes after and before the argument.', usage=MyParser.msg())
parser.add_argument('text', help='"News Text" for classification (Required Parameter)')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This type of argument fails with Unrecognized error:

```
>>> python3.5 file.py "Apps infected by Gooligan include "Perfect Cleaner," and more."
Error: unrecognized arguments: Cleaner, and more.
```

And sometimes without any error:

```
>>> python3.5 file.py "Now "Support is expensive, and, when you're Google or any other vendor," said Michael Jude."
>
```

I want to know reason of second type errors and solution for handle errors in my code without any attention to argument.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an `argparse` issue.  It's a matter of how the shell splits the input line, and passes it to Python.  Look at `sys.argv` to see what `argparse` has to work with.

I believe backslash allows you to include quotes and other special characters in the strings - but experiement.

From the side bar:
[Python argparse argument with quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168666/python-argparse-argument-with-quotes)

Comment: You could also try single quotes around the whole argument.

Comment: @kindall But beware that single quotes in a single-quoted string *cannot* be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike what many people believe, it's not the shell that splits command line into arguments. It's not the process loader either, although it does some parsing and interpretation of its own.

Command line is parsed into argument vector by python process itself. Depending on how python is built, that would be some sort of run-time library. For windows build, that would be most likely MS Visual C++ runtime library. More details about how it parses command line can be found in Visual C++ documentation: [Parsing C++ command-Line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019#parsing-c-command-line-arguments).

To see unprocessed command line, one could use this code:

```
import win32api
print(win32api.GetCommandLine())
```